# Replacing the content of a div with the content of another hidden div in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to replace the content of a div with the content of another div(which is hidden). The code works for the first time only but the second time doesn't work at all.
I have a div where the titles of some articles are scrolling. I want to achieve that:everytime i am going to click the title of an article its content(the content is in hidden div) is going to appear in another div with the id="sreen".

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//everytime you click the title of an article

$("a.title").live("click", function(){

//replace the content of div screen with the content of an article

$('div#screen').replaceWith($(this).next('div.content'));


    });

</script>
```

Any ideas???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `.replaceWith` will effectively remove `div#screen`.  So using `.html()` will be what you want to do to maintain the element `div#screen`.

You mentioned that your formating is not working correctly which leads me to believe you have css classes on `div.content`.  Calling `.html()` on `div.content` will ommit the root node of div.content.

```
<div class="content">
 <span>some text</span>
</div>
```

`$("div.content").html()` will produce `<span>some text</span>`

If my assumptions are correct you might want to look at using [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) which will clone the current object without events or `clone(true)` to include any data and events.

```
var $content = $(this).next('div.content').clone();
$content.css("display", "block");
$('div#screen').html($content);
```

Another way of doing this would be use .outerHTML

```
$("a.title").live("click", function() {
  $('div#screen').html($(this).next('div.content')[0].outerHTML); 
});
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/GhqnB/1/).

Comment: Thank you Mark,i used the clone approach and it worked perfectly.Yeah, i have classes inside the div content.Although the answer Gaby gave was correct,too but led me to change my css.Now everything works great as it should be!!!

Answer (score 0):

use the [`.html`<sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/html) method for this

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

//everytime you click the title of an article
$("a.title").live("click", function(){
    //replace the content of div screen with the content of an article
    $('div#screen').html( $(this).next('div.content').html() );

     });

</script>
```

Comment: I tried your approach and it works great.But the format of the content shown in the new div is not as that i was expecting.Anyway thanks for your answer.A weird thing is that if i omit .html() from the end of the command the works again,the content is shown in the format i want but only for one time per article.

Comment: @user, that happens because when you give an element as parameter it gets moved from the DOM and is reinserted to the new place. Once you replace it with something else the previous element gets overwritten.

Comment: @User, @Mark's updated answer might be what you are ultimately looking for.